# Additional filtering parameters in #fuelux datagrid

Tags: fuelux

Does the fuelux datagrid support adding additional filter options?  I would like - for instance - to add (next to the filter dropdown you already have in place), a checkbox which should also be added as a parameter to my function that retrieves the data remotely from the server.

It would be nice if the grid would automatically take any parameters from input elements that we can mark by adding a specific class or data- attribute.

Thanks very much! :)

David.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this.

1. Add filtering logic to the datasource you provide, keyed off any custom property you add to the datasource.
2. Add the checkbox within the datagrid markup (or anywhere).
3. When your checkbox is clicked, update the custom property on your datasource and then call `$('#MyGrid').datagrid('reload')` to tell the datagrid to reread your datasource

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the feedback, but how do I know - within the datasource method, which grid has triggered this?

Reason I ask is that we want to have a GENERIC function for the data and columns functions, and we would like to have just one parameter passed to the function which would contain the grid element so we can have data- attributes on there that we cean read to get - for instance - the url where we need to remotely fetch the data...

Again - thanks for your help - much appreciated!

Comment: It is not easy to set it up exactly how you're saying because the datagrid/datasource interaction just wasn't designed that way.  Ideally you will have an instance of a datasource for each URL or type of data you're working with.  Then, instantiate each datagrid with the proper datasource.  Done!

Comment: Yes, I know, but since we can't always predict what grids will be on one page, we try to avoid using ID's at all times, and to reduce the amount of Javascript, we prefer / try to have ONE method for all grids which just takes some metadata using data- attributes.  That's how we usually work...  One of the data parameters would be data-url which contains the url of where to fetch the data...  It's a bit difficult / strange that we can not retrieve the datagrid instance in the methods... that would fix everything (in normal jquery events for instance, you can always grab back to $(this)...)

Comment: If that's your preference, you can store the URL with the datagrid by adding it to the dataOptions:

$('#MyGrid').datagrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    dataOptions: { dataUrl: 'MYURL' }
});

Then, the datagrid will pass this URL into your datasource as part of the options object on each call.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the dataOptions parameter is exactly what I needed!  Thanks very much!